# Grails REST plugin using HTTPBuilder for HTTPS

Tags: rest, grails, httpbuilder

I have a service method in grails that was working fine.

It pulls a JSON via a GET request.  After moving to prod we had to change the protocol to HTTPS and now I am getting an exception.

Is there anything I have to change to use the HTTPS protocol?  I look all over [The HTTPBuilder Documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html) and I could not find a single reference to using HTTPS.  I also could not find a example on Google.

```
            def reportList = new ArrayList()
        def result
        //TODO Dynamic PatientKey
        def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'https://mydomain/servicename?key=' + key )


        reportList = null
        http.request( GET, JSON ) { req ->

          headers.Accept = 'application/json'


          response.success = { resp, reader ->

            reportList = reader.getAt("patientReports")

          }


        }

    }
    [ reportList : reportList ]
```

Comment: what's the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Grails plugin solution works well in a test or local env because Same-Origin Policy will prevent you from implementing a front-end jQuery AJAX call since the domains are different.

In Prod, since HTTPS was used, and since the domains are the same, a jQuery AJAX call works much better then having the logic in the controller and using the REST plugin.

```
$.getJSON('${YOUR_URL}', function(data){ var yourData = data.yourData; //Operate on data here });
```

Answer (score 2):

Whats the exception you are getting? 
please check that SSL certificate is valid for the website. More here.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/ssl.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  We just ended up going with a front-end jQuery solution however.